# debugging loop c++ undefined variable, what type? Hoglund

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have been reading one of the Hoglund titles and I though, reading great, but can I make it work?  Why do they provide non-working examples in books?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    DEBUG_EVENT dbg_evt;
    int aPID;

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("wrong number of params\nusage %s<pid>\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    //load the ptr to fDebugSetProcessKillOnExit
    fDebugSetProcessKillOnExit = (DEBUGSETPROCESSKILLONEXIT)
    GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), 
    "DebugSetProcessKillOnExit");
    if(!fDebugSetProcessKillOnExit)
    {
        printf("[!] failed to get fDebugSetProcessKillOnExit function!\n");
    }

    aPID = atoi(argv[1]);
}
```

I am getting two error messages:

1. `fDebugSetProcessKillOnExit is an undeclared identifier`
   What type should it be?
2. `"Error 4 error C2664: 'GetModuleHandleW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [13]' to 'LPCWSTR'`
   What type should the `fDebug...` be?  Why doesn't the `aPid = atoi...` line work?

Should the project be compiled in C instead of C++, as this is exactly as it is in the book?

Thanks, R.

Comment: every time I see this "microsoft c" I think I'm looking at another language.

Comment: did you check errata for examples?

Comment: Chris, that's funny :)

osgx, I did but there doesn't seem to be any, i'm tired, I probably missed them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking this from MSDN:

```
BOOL WINAPI DebugSetProcessKillOnExit(__in  BOOL KillOnExit);
```

you can declare the function pointer as:

```
BOOL (*fDebugSetProcessKillOnExit)(BOOL) = /* ... */;
```

or ease your eyes by using `typedef`:

```
typedef BOOL (*DebugKillPtr)(BOOL);
DebugKillPtr fDebugSetProcessKillOnExit = /* ... */;
```

Function pointers can be somewhat confusing, [InformITs guide on them](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=140) should help with that.

Additionally, you are using a Unicode build. You can either use `GetModuleHandle(L"Kernel32.dll")` or `_T()` etc. or set your project to use the multi-byte-character-set *(project properties -> configuration -> general -> character set)*.

The unicode-character-set is also the reason why the `atoi()` statement can't work:
`argv` is an array of `_TCHAR*`s, and `_TCHAR` is `wchar_t` for unicode-builds. `atoi()` however expects a `const char*` argument and you are handing it a `wchar_t*`.
So you can either again use a multi-byte-character set, convert the string or use Microsofts [`_wtoi()`/`_ttoi()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd5xkb5c%28VS.80%29.aspx).

To ease switching between character sets and stick with the style of the book, prefer the `_T*` and `_t*` versions.

Comment: I did change the project to use the multi-byte character set.  I am curious as to know why each is advantageous or not?  Yay, it works.  Thanks.

Comment: Note the last comment - if you stick to the `_t*`/`_T*` style you shouldn't need to worry about switching character sets. See here for MS' take on MBCS & UCS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwe8bzh0%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. The declaration for fDebugSetProcessKillOnExit is missing; probably it should be something like

```
DEBUGSETPROCESSKILLONEXIT fDebugSetProcessKillOnExit;
```

where DEBUGSETPROCESSKILLONEXIT should be a typedef to the prototype of that function.

2. You are compiling in Unicode and the book "thinks" that you're compiling in ANSI; you should change the strings passed to the APIs to generic strings with the _T() macro.

So, to sum everything up, you should simply change one line and add the typedef:

```
typedef BOOL (*DEBUGSETPROCESSKILLONEXIT)(BOOL);
//load the ptr to fDebugSetProcessKillOnExit
DEBUGSETPROCESSKILLONEXIT fDebugSetProcessKillOnExit = (DEBUGSETPROCESSKILLONEXIT) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(_T("kernel32.dll")), _T("DebugSetProcessKillOnExit"));
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was really interested in the unicode to multi-byte part of the question but it was a difficult choice.  Thanks.